# Return values from one column based on sum range for given criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with columns `A`, `B` and `C`, all values in columns are in ascending order. `Column A` has serial number, `column B` has names and `column C` has quantities.

When I enter a name for example in `cell L2` and in `cell M2` required quantity let's say 540 the macro should search name from `cell L2` in `column B` and sum all values for that name until sum is matched with value from `cell M2`.  When sum is matched, copy(return) all serial numbers in `column A` from that sum range in `column N`.

I manually made an example how it should look.
[image: Screenshot example]

I made the same question on another forum but no answers (https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/reverse-sumif-return-column-values-based-on-sum-criteria.1179552/)

Comment: How is the code supposed to know if it's L2 or L3 etc that it's trying to find. Will it just be the last row in column L that it will sum or all of the items in column L? Then also what is up with the colours?

Comment: Hello,  only search value is in L2, i added that green value (L3) and colors are just for more detail explanation.  
Mirko

Comment: So does column N need to be cleared before it adds the new list?

Comment: That woud be great. Here is the link to sample workbook if needed: https://easyupload.io/8k12xq

Comment: One last thing is it exactly match M2 or closest? What if it isn't exact match?

Comment: Yea, greate question.  IF its a exact match, return exact match, if not add  to sum range one next value. For example if i search for S-400139-30A (yellow value in picture example) 500 Items then show  sum for 540.  If u can understan what i want to say :D Always round up for higher value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how this works for you:

```
Sub GetSerialNo()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lRowInput As Long, lRowResults As Long, i As Long
Dim arr, SName As String, SQuantity As Double, CurQuantity As Double
Dim MatchList(), MatchCount As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Blanko List") 'Your sheet name
lRowInput = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Last row of data
lRowResults = ws.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Last row of previous results
arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & lRowInput).Value 'Populate the array
SName = ws.Range("L2").Value 'Search name
SQuantity = ws.Range("M2").Value 'Search Quantity
CurQuantity = 0 'Ensure these 2 values are 0
MatchCount = 0

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'Loop from row 1 to last row
    If arr(i, 2) = SName Then 'If name = search name
        If arr(i,3) > 0 Then 'New line to skip quantities of 0
            CurQuantity = CurQuantity + arr(i, 3) 'add quantity
            MatchCount = MatchCount + 1 'Add match count
            ReDim Preserve MatchList(1 To MatchCount) 'Resize the matchlist array to add a new row
            MatchList(UBound(MatchList)) = arr(i, 1) 'Add the name to new row of matchlist
            If CurQuantity >= SQuantity Then Exit For 'If the quantity is equal or greater than search quantity then exit the loop
        End if 
    End If
Next i

ws.Range("N2:N" & lRowResults + 1).ClearContents 'Clear previous results list
ws.Range("N2").Resize(UBound(MatchList)).Value = Application.Transpose(MatchList) 'Dump new results into column N
If CurQuantity < SQuantity Then
    MsgBox "The available quantity is less than the desired quantity." & vbCr & vbCr & _
    "Desired: " & SQuantity & vbCr & "Available: " & CurQuantity & vbCr & _
    "Difference: " & CurQuantity - SQuantity, vbExclamation, "Missing Quantities"
End If

End Sub
```

I've added comments to each line so you can hopefully follow along to what it is doing.

I also just added the detection if the available quantity is less than the desired. You can obviously change exactly what the message box says to what you want.

Comment: Code works like Vienna Philharmonic orchestra :D  Thank you man u saved me a good time.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.

Comment: I should point out that if you ask for a bigger quantity than what is in the list then it will give you all of it but will obviously be short on how much. A simple add-in can fix that.

Comment: Just one more thing.  It would be usefull if some mesage box could be added when there there is not enough items to sum. For example i search for 1000 items and in list is only 900.

Comment: try the new code. You will obviously also need to change from xlsx file type to xlsm in order to save the macro but Excel will tell you that when you try if you haven't already.

Comment: Hello man, just to say once again thanks for help with this code, its life saving macro :D I have one question if its okay. Is it possible to modify code to skip serials where quantity value is 0 (zero)?  I menage to modify array range so that code can work on my other worksheet, its a same job for code. But there some serials have 0 (zero) as value. I would like to skip them from listing in result column. If u have time, can u help me with that?

Comment: Hi I updated it, it's just a matter of adding the line `If arr(i,3) > 0 Then` and the corresponding `End If`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: You are the best!